# Как предотвратить слияние смайлов в JS

Tags: javascript, кодировка, emoji

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Смайлы ‍ и ♂ при любом виде соединения (+, str.concat(), join) соединяются в единый смайл ‍♂ (даже при вводе сдесь, на stack overflow поочередно)

Как это предотвратить? Возможно ли поставить какой-то разделитель, который не будет учитываться при копировании? В телеграме проверял, так же работает((

Comment: [Zero-width non-joiner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_non-joiner) возможно?

Comment: @andreymal по дефолту его видно в html коде в отладке браузера между двумя нужными смайлами. Но если даблкликнуть для редактирования текста - опять сольются. А именно в тегах сайта он никак не отображается

Comment: Даблкликнуть где куда, о чём речь?

Comment: Я тут скопировал первый смайл из вашего вопроса и обнаружил, что к нему прилеплен zero-width joiner. Думаю, если вы уберёте этот символ из смайла, то проблема решится

Comment: Например попробуйте скопировать у меня 

Answer (score 2):

Как подсказал [andreymal](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1349900/#comment2392887_1349900) использовать Unicode символ [Zero-width](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_non-joiner) (`\u200c`)

```js
console.log('‍'+'♀️');
console.log('‍'+'\u200c'+'♀️');
console.log('‍'+'♂️');
console.log('‍'+'\u200c'+'♂️');
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100vh !important; height: 100vh;}
.as-console-row-code {font-size: 235% !important;}
```

Comment: Глобально - это решение для отображения. Но по факту это еще дополнительный символ, который сохраняется при копировании. В вопросе не написал, но я столкнулся с проблемой при шифровании текста смайликами, там наличие каких-либо других сиимволов недопустимо..

Comment: @shumik_UA, ну так тогда не надо заменять ничего.

Comment: @Qwertiy у меня словарь с символами "‍a|4@#♂". При шифровании случается так, что символ ♂ становится после ‍, тогда они при чтении объеденяются в один символ и ломают шрифт.

Comment: @shumik_UA, нет, проверяй лучше. Ничего не должно ломаться.

Comment: @Qwertiy что проверять?) Попробуй создать фукцию, в которую передашь строку с последовательными смайлами ‍ и ♂, а она разобьет их опять на два смайла без побочных символов. А если передать ‍♂ то он должен остаться собой)

Comment: @shumik_UA как я уже писал, в вашем первом смайле всё ещё есть символ zero-width joiner, удалите его всё-таки

Comment: @shumik_UA, почему на 2, а не на 3? Ты что-то странное делаешь.

Comment: @Qwertiy потому что 1: ‍ 2: ♂